# Jasmine Cold Marble with toPromise - never ending await

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, jasmine-marbles

I have a debtService which calls backend API with simple HttpClient request. It returns an observable. Now, in AppComponent, I'm calling debtService's method to fetch debt. I want to make sure, that when debt is fetched, also the method called logGetDebtAttempt is being called.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, Subscriber, TeardownLogic } from 'rxjs';
import { DebtService } from './services/debt.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private debtService: DebtService) {
  }

  async getDebt() {
    // getNationalDebt() returns Observable<Number>
    await this.debtService.getNationalDebt().toPromise();
    this.logGetDebtAttempt();
  }

  logGetDebtAttempt() {
  }
}
```

That's why I wrote such test:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { cold } from 'jasmine-marbles';
import { Observable, Subscriber, TeardownLogic } from 'rxjs';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DebtService } from './services/debt.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing'


const chartServiceStub = {
  getNationalDebt(): Observable<Number> {
    return cold('--x|', { x: 1 });
  }
};

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: DebtService, useValue: chartServiceStub },
        
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should test', async () => {
    spyOn(component, 'getDebt').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(component, 'logGetDebtAttempt').and.callThrough();

    await component.getDebt();

    expect(component.logGetDebtAttempt).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

When running tests, **await component.getDebt();** never ends and it creates a timeout.

Could someone please explain why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This won't completely answer your question.

I am thinking it happens because of the `--` syntax where each dash is one millisecond.

From my experience, I was never a fan of `jasmine-marbles` or any marble testing helping library because of those dashes.

For your scenario, you don't even need marbles. You can use `of`.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
const chartServiceStub = {
  getNationalDebt(): Observable<Number> {
    return of(1);
  }
};

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: DebtService, useValue: chartServiceStub },
        
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should test', async () => {
    spyOn(component, 'getDebt').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(component, 'logGetDebtAttempt').and.callThrough();

    await component.getDebt();

    expect(component.logGetDebtAttempt).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

And also, since it is a `.toPromise`, I would do a `take(1)` on it too. I think having this `take`, it might help with the marbles scenario as well. I know this is an http call most likely and the `take` is not needed but you could argue that it is better design because if I am going to use `await`, the stream cannot emit forever.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, Subscriber, TeardownLogic } from 'rxjs';
import { DebtService } from './services/debt.service';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private debtService: DebtService) {
  }

  async getDebt() {
    // getNationalDebt() returns Observable<Number>
    await this.debtService.getNationalDebt().pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
    this.logGetDebtAttempt();
  }

  logGetDebtAttempt() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for similar answers to your question and I just found a paragraph within [the rxjs documentation](https://v6.rxjs.dev/guide/testing/marble-testing) here that reads:

> At this time, the `TestScheduler` can only be used to test code that uses RxJS schedulers - `AsyncScheduler`, etc. If the code consumes a Promise, for example, it cannot be reliably tested with TestScheduler, but instead should be tested more traditionally. See the Known Issues section for more details.

The [known issues section](https://v6.rxjs.dev/guide/testing/marble-testing#known-issues) goes into slightly more detail about not testing promises. But this leads me to believe that if you use promises within your code, you can not use marbles for testing.